# Perl XML::Compile "error: too few 'any' elements, got 0 for minimum 1 at person#any"

Tags: xml, perl

somehow could not get XML::Compile working with very simple XSD file that contains

```
<xs:any />
```

without it it works perfect. Looks like I am missing something very simple.

Here is test1.xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:any />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element></xs:schema>
```

Here is test1.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Compile::Schema;
use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my @specs  = ('test1.xsd');
my $schema = XML::Compile::Schema->new(\@specs); 

my $data = 
{ 
     firstname => 'Alex',
     lastname => 'Muster',
     email => 'amuster@abc.com',
};

my $doc    = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $write  = $schema->compile(WRITER => 'person');
my $xml    = $write->($doc, $data);

$doc->setDocumentElement($xml);
print $doc->toString(1);
```

Error message is:

```
error: too few 'any' elements, got 0 for minimum 1 at person#any
```

Comment: @serenesat: It seems pointless to edit an answer just to remove "Thank you". By all means remove stuff like that if the post needs editing anyway (although this question is really good) but otherwise it does no harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put `<xs:any />` into a schema and expect the writer to randomly come up with some sort of XML element just to make it valid

Every item in the schema must have a name so that data for it can be provided

If you remove the `<xs:any />` you will get this semi-successful result

```
mistake: tag `email' not used at person
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
  <firstname>Alex</firstname>
  <lastname>Muster</lastname>
</person>
```

which is saying that it has nowhere to put the `email` information. The other elements, however, are created correctly

If you have in mind something specific you want to be generated for the `<xs:any />` then it looks like you can 
specify the behaviour you want for the `any_type` option. The documentation says this about it

```
any_type => CODE  
       [1.07] how to handle "anyType" type elements. Supported values  
       depends on the backend, specializations of  
       XML::Compile::Translate.
```

***I'm sorry, the documentation for `XML::Compile::Translate` says*** **"Currently only supported for the reader. "** ***so you can't specify what is generated for the `<xs:any />` element when*** **writing** ***XML***